# Sort a PHP array bringing back mixed results

Tags: php, arrays, sorting

How would one sort this array,alphabetically. I'm printing this array by using the following code

`<?php print_r($artists); ?>`

and thought doing some sort of

`<?php ksort($artists); ?>` or `<?php asort($artists); ?>`

before I print out `$artists` would work but it's bringing back mixed results.

```
Array ( [0] =>
Bloor, Simon

[1] =>
Bloor, Tom

[2] =>
Burt, Theo

[3] =>
Berendes, Eva

[4] =>
Barnes, Kristian

[5] =>
Bajo, Elena

)
```

Thanks, and if you need any more information, please do not hesitate to ask.
R

**UPDATE**

Added a full-code snippi here: http://snippi.com/s/14ox0cx

I have added `var_dump($artists)` before and after `sort($artists)` and shown an example of the before/after output here.

Hope this helps...

```
<h1>Before</h1>
<?php var_dump($artists); ?>

<?php sort($artists); ?>

<h1>After</h1>
<?php var_dump($artists); ?>

Before

array(6) { [0]=> string(97) "
Bloor, Simon

" [1]=> string(95) "
Bloor, Tom

" [2]=> string(95) "
Burt, Theo

" [3]=> string(140) "
Berendes, Eva

" [4]=> string(107) "
Barnes, Kristian

" [5]=> string(99) "
Bajo, Elena

" }

After

array(6) { [0]=> string(140) "
Berendes, Eva

" [1]=> string(97) "
Bloor, Simon

" [2]=> string(95) "
Bloor, Tom

" [3]=> string(95) "
Burt, Theo

" [4]=> string(107) "
Barnes, Kristian

" [5]=> string(99) "
Bajo, Elena

" }
```

Comment: have you not just tried `sort()`?

Comment: Why the &$artists? You do not manipulate $artists. Maybe that is at least part of the problem? I am talking about Line 35. of your snippi:  `<?php foreach ( $groups as $letter => &$artists ) : ?>`

Comment: Thanks, I'll remove it.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in the comments, [sort](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.sort.php) does work.

```
$artists = array ( 
 'Bloor, Simon', 
 'Bloor, Tom', 
 'Burt, Theo', 
 'Berendes, Eva', 
 'Barnes, Kristian', 
 'Bajo, Elena');

sort($artists);
print_r($artists);
```

See some proof of this code [here](http://ideone.com/wVdziO)

Comment: Thanks for your help. I've added sort($artists) but it still doesn't sort them as your code does... http://snippi.com/s/14ox0cx

Comment: @rdck you still use ksort in line 34 in that snippi `<?php ksort($groups); ?>` ?8-( oh, but that is for groups. Can you add <?php var_dump($artists); ?> before line 38 and after line 38 and then show us the output here? Maybe in an update to your question, also refferencing your snippi? That would help

Comment: Thanks for this. I have done so and added to original question. Thanks so much.

Answer (score 0):

ksort() is not what you want; it sorts by key and that leaves the array as-is.
asort(): if that "fails" for you just a wild guess: you are using a `for($i=0; $i<count($arr);...` loop to iterate the array? That leaves the output as-is since asort() keeps the array keys.

Try a simple [sort()](http://docs.php.net/sort) or [natsort()](http://docs.php.net/natsort) and a [foreach](http://docs.php.net/foreach) loop.

```
<?php
$arr = array (
    'Bloor, Simon',
    'Bloor, Tom',
    'Burt, Theo',
    'Berendes, Eva',
    'Barnes, Kristian',
    'Bajo, Elena'
);

natsort($arr);

foreach($arr as $e) {
    echo $e, "\r\n";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

[ksort()](http://php.net/ksort): sorts an array by its keys, not valid here if you want to sort the array alphabetically.

[ksort()](http://php.net/ksort): Sort an array and maintain index association

You may use [sort()](http://php.net/sort): Simply sorts the array!

```
<?php
$artists = array ("Bloor, Simon", "Bloor, Tom", "Burt, Theo", "Berendes, Eva", "Barnes, Krist", "Bajo, Elena");

print_r($artists);

$artists = array ("Bloor, Simon", "Bloor, Tom", "Burt, Theo", "Berendes, Eva", "Barnes, Krist", "Bajo, Elena");
ksort($artists);
print_r($artists);

$artists = array ("Bloor, Simon", "Bloor, Tom", "Burt, Theo", "Berendes, Eva", "Barnes, Krist", "Bajo, Elena");
asort($artists);
print_r($artists);

$artists = array ("Bloor, Simon", "Bloor, Tom", "Burt, Theo", "Berendes, Eva", "Barnes, Krist", "Bajo, Elena");
sort($artists);
print_r($artists);

?>
```

[Simple DEMO](http://ideone.com/g1RfUJ)

Comment: Thanks for your help. I've added sort($artists) but it still doesn't sort them as your code does... http://snippi.com/s/14ox0cx

Comment: @rdck can you please provide $artists sample?!

Comment: I am using ACF and the 'repeater', so `$artists` is (http://www.advancedcustomfields.com/resources/field-types/repeater/) but let me know what you need exactly.